# Angular 6 not validating conditional [required]

Tags: angular

I have the following field in an NgForm:

```
<input type="text" name="depVarName" [(ngModel)]="variable.depVarName" 
       #depVarName="ngModel" id="depVarName"  
       [required]="'depSelected>0'" />
<div *ngIf="submitted" class="errorMsg">
   <label *ngIf="depVarName.control.hasError('required')">Dependency is required</label>
</div>
```

The problem is that this field is always required, regardless of the `[required]` related condition `depSelected>0`. `depSelected` is not a DOM element, could that be the problem?

Comment: Can you show component code?

Comment: You're passing the string (note the single quotes) `'depSelected>0'`. A non-empty string is always truthy. So it's always required

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently `'depSelected>0'`(non-empty `string`) is considered as `truthy` and that's why field marked as `required`. The expression inside require attribute should be without `'`(single qoute).

```
[required]="depSelected>0"
```

Comment: yeah, what Pankaj said. With the quotes, you make it a string value, rather than an actual expression